# how can I show "hand loan" given to my friend in tax filling?

Tags: india, personal-loan

In last financial year, I have given hand loan of 2 Lakh rupees to my friend. I would like to show this in tax filling.

Which head/section of tax filling, I can use to show these details?

Comment: What do you mean by hand loan, are you saying in cash? Is the country India?

Comment: why would a loan be of interest for tax filing? you don't get a tex reduction (or increase) for giving a loan??

Comment: Yes it is in cash and the country is India. I agree, I won't be getting tax reduction. But I want to be transparent and just wanted to show the amount, in tax filling.